# How to add classes to dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

Before you say this is a duplicate, I've already looked at some answers for the same question but none seem to fix my issue. I have a dynamically created table from firebase. Its working fine and everything shows like it should but I had an idea to add color to the text depending on if they are going to meet their goal. When I tried adding an If/Else statement then it just shows the first table in color and everything else is white (which is default font color).

```
    salesBySold.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();

    let dayDividedByMonth = current_date/days_in_month;
    let tracking_sold_math = childData.cars_sold/dayDividedByMonth;

    if (tracking_sold_math < childData.goal) {
      $('#cars_sold').addClass('red-text');
    } else {
      $('#cars_sold').addClass('green-text')
    };

    $('#salesperson_tbody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>${childData.name}</td>
            <td id='cars_sold'>${childData.cars_sold}</td>
            <td>${childData.goal}<td>
        </tr>
    `);


  });
});
```

So this is my code and it just adds colored text to the first  but every other one is still default color. I wanted them all to be colored correctly

Comment: it seems you try to add a class to an element which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yeah, I had it up front before but must have changed it back as it still didnt work as I just copied and pasted my current code for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are setting class of id="cars_sold" in loop that's fine but it will append class to all previously added td so for solution you should do this

```
     salesBySold.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();

    let dayDividedByMonth = current_date/days_in_month;
    let tracking_sold_math = childData.cars_sold/dayDividedByMonth;
    var cls='';
    if (tracking_sold_math < childData.goal) {
      cls='red-text';
    } else {
     cls='green-text';
    };

    $('#salesperson_tbody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>${childData.name}</td>
            <td id='cars_sold' class="${cls}">${childData.cars_sold}</td>
            <td>${childData.goal}<td>
        </tr>
    `);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I had the if/else statement up front before but I must have changed it back. I did not think about the var class though! Thats pretty clever, Thanks again